# How to display an image from the user module in PyroCMS?

Tags: html, content-management-system, pyrocms, pyro

I'm trying to get the image URL which is stored in the user module, using the following code:

```
{{ user:profile user_id="3" }}

{{ display_name }}

{{ company }}

{{ profile_picture }} 

{{ /user:profile }}
```

`{{ profile_picture }}` is the image and all that appears as 'Array' on the page. The other variables appear as I would like them to, images have just been giving me problems. The image is properly store in the File module, I just can't seem to get it to appear on the page.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`profile_picture` is an array. You'll have to access the subelement of `image` if you want the image URL.

```
{{ user:profile user_id="3" }}
  {{ profile_picture:image }}
{{ /user:profile }}
```